# Reload/ Refresh Mechanism

Tags: html, reload, page-refresh

I would like to know the mechanism behind reloading/ refreshing a Webpage. My questions are- 
1. Does reloading/ refreshing a webpage that completely failed to load earlier always result in instant loading of the entire webpage correctly with all its contents?
2. Or does it result in delayed loading of the entire webpage?
3. Or does it result in delayed loading of the webpage with some contents (Ex. images) missing?
4. Or does it do nothing? ie., the page still fails to load because the server is down?

I know that all these scenarios are possible. But I would like to know what causes each of these above scenarios? (For Ex. is it the server being down or busy or the content not being available anymore?)

Also I would like to know what happens in these two cases-
->when content is fetched from a single server 
->when content is fetched from multiple servers

Answer (score 0):

1. Reloading does not always result in instant loading of the entire webpage correctly.  There are many different reason a page may not load correctly, many of them simply reloading the page will not fix.  There are so any reasons there really isn't time to explain here.
2. I should load with the same data it received before reloading the page.  Unless something has changed in the interim.
3. If the server is down.  Reloading the page will not result in the page loading correctly the second time.
4. When content is fetched from a single server the content comes from just that server.  When content is served from multiple servers,  say the images are being served from a CDN, they are loaded from those places.

Reloading a page does nothing different that when you first visit a page.  Although in certain circumstances the local browser cache may be reset.